# Populate Tuple list with SQlite data Xamarin

Tags: c#, list, sqlite, xamarin.forms, tuples

I have a Xamarin App that I primarily write in C#.
In de app I've got a SQlite database in which I store an Int (ID), a string and two doubles.

I need the string and two doubles in a Tuple list.

Altohugh I figured out how to put the information in a normal list, I don't know how to put it in a Tuple.

How I populated the normal list:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        devListLoc.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetAllLocations();
    }
```

How I populate Tuple without SQlite:

```
List list = new List<Tuple<string, double, double>>
        {
            new Tuple<string, double, double>("tesst1", 57.434180, 7.236162),
            new Tuple<string, double, double>("test2", 58.435602, 8.234298),
        };
```

So I want to populate the Tuple list in kindof the same way, but I can't figure out how, nor can I find the answer somewhere else.

Cheers!

Edit:
The GetAllLocations task:

```
public Task<List<BarLoc>> GetAllLocations()
    {
        return database.QueryAsync<BarLoc>("SELECT * FROM [BarLoc]");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

var locations = await App.Database.GetAllLocations();

var tuples = (from l in locations 
              select new Tuple<string,double,double>(l.Name, l.Lat, l.Long)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it gets the following error: 
Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'Task<List<BarLoc>>'. 'Select' not found
I added the GetAllLocations Task code in the question because thats what it's talking about. (And I forgot adding it, whoops)

Comment: you need to await it - I left that out of my original response